# Checking reason behind node failure

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have `docker swarm` setup with nodes running `node-1, node-2 and node-3`. Due to some reason everyday one of my node is getting failed basically they exits. I ran `docker logs <container id of swarm>` but logs doesn't contains any info related to node failure.

So, is there any logs file where a log related to this failure can be seen? or this is due to some less memory allocation problem?

Can any one suggest me how to dig this problem and find a proper solution. As everyday I have to start by swarm nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Like most containers, Swarm containers run and exit unless you use `docker run` with the `-d` option to "daemonize" them. For example:

```
$ docker run -d swarm join --advertise=172.30.0.69:2375 consul://172.30.0.161:8500
```

On the other hand, if you used Docker Machine to create the VMs, then also [use Docker Machine to create the Swarm manager and nodes](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/provision-with-machine/). By default, Docker Machine applies TLS authentication to the Docker Engine nodes. The easiest thing to do is to also create the Swarm manager and nodes at the same time as you create the Docker Engine nodes.

For more info, check out the [brand new Swarm doc](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/).

Comment: In my structure, all swarm agents are running using the same command as what you mentioned with {{-d}} also a swarm manager is running. My main problem is when any of my swarm agent goes down the logs related to it are lot good enough to identify why agent got exited?

Apart from this I am also running all docker commands with {{--restart}} flag, just to restart them again whenever they exit.

Comment: Maybe search here for someone who has had the same issue. And if not, create a new post. Be sure to provide enough info so that people reading the question can understand your scenario: https://forums.docker.com/c/open-source-projects/swarm